# Actionbarsherlock switch Actionbar Overlay Mode programmatic

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

i use Actionbarsherlock for my App and i like to switch the Actionbar Overlay Mode in my Code.
I have 2 Fragments (one is a Mapview where i want a translucent Actionbar) the other is a ListFragment where a solid Actionbar is needed.

i tryed

```
requestWindowFeature((int) Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR & ~Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

problem with this is that requesting Features only works before content is added.

i using this style to accomplish the transparent Actionbar

```
<style name="TransparentActionbar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="abBackground">#96000000</item>
    <item name="abDivider">@null</item>
</style>
```

is there a way to set

```
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

to false inside the Activity/Fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Sadly it doesnt work for Actionbarsherlock and a ListFragment from the Compatibility Package.
Top Margin is added to the Bottom Margin for some reason. Left and Right Margin working fine inside the LayoutListener.

Found a solution for this Problem in an [Android Developer Example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/src/com/example/android/hcgallery/TitlesFragment.html)

```
// Attach a GlobalLayoutListener so that we get a callback when the layout
// has finished drawing. This is necessary so that we can apply top-margin
// to the ListView in order to dodge the ActionBar. Ordinarily, that's not
// necessary, but we've set the ActionBar to "overlay" mode using our theme,
// so the layout does not account for the action bar position on its own.
ViewTreeObserver observer = getListView().getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);

// Because the fragment doesn't have a reliable callback to notify us when
// the activity's layout is completely drawn, this OnGlobalLayoutListener provides
// the necessary callback so we can add top-margin to the ListView in order to dodge
// the ActionBar. Which is necessary because the ActionBar is in overlay mode, meaning
// that it will ordinarily sit on top of the activity layout as a top layer and
// the ActionBar height can vary. Specifically, when on a small/normal size screen,
// the action bar tabs appear in a second row, making the action bar twice as tall.
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener layoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int barHeight = getActivity().getActionBar().getHeight();
        ListView listView = getListView();
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) listView.getLayoutParams();
        // The list view top-margin should always match the action bar height
        if (params.topMargin != barHeight) {
            params.topMargin = barHeight;
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        // The action bar doesn't update its height when hidden, so make top-margin zero
        if (!getActivity().getActionBar().isShowing()) {
          params.topMargin = 0;
          listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Great find, just what I needed. For those reading there's one more thing: in the sample they also remove the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` from the `ViewTreeObserver` in `onDestroyView()`. Like this: `getListView().getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(mLayoutListener);` Might be important.